# Implementing / replacing RS232 cable with Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I have posted this on several forums - without success.
I am asking SIMPLE hardware question and expecting just yes or no answer. Please follow my instruction.

Background

Bluetooth has "SPP" - serial protocol "feature".
My "remote Bluetooth device " adapter identifies as "SPP__CA".

My question is :

Do I have to have "local Bluetooth adapter" identified as "SPP"?
Or as "SPP_CA"?

AKA
do both ends of the Bluetooth "replacing Rs232 cable " hardware have
to have  "SPP" in their identification ?

PS I am NOT calling "SPP_CA" as "service" - I only know it by "name" as part of the adapter description ...

Answer (score 4):

> I have posted this on several forums - without success. I am asking SIMPLE hardware question and expecting just yes or no answer. Please follow my instruction.

No. This is not ChatGPT.

> Do I have to have "local Bluetooth adapter" identified as "SPP"? Or as "SPP_CA"?
>
> AKA do both ends of the Bluetooth "replacing Rs232 cable " hardware have to have "SPP" in their identification ?

None of the above. The Bluetooth [Serial Port Profile 1.2 specification](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/serial-port-profile-1-2/) makes **no mention** of any special requirements for the adapter name. Any device regardless of its description can offer the SPP service through an SDP (Bluetooth **Service Discovery Protocol**) Service Record, with the UUID of 0x1101. (Only the "server" device needs this, the "client" device doesn't need to advertise any service.)

(Pre-Android era phones used to provide an AT-compatible modem interface via SPP, with neither the phone nor the computer having "SPP" anywhere in their descriptions.)

[image: Screenshot of the "SDP Service Record" table]

Comment: Beautiful answer.  I was typing up 1/2 as good answer with the same information when yours popped in. :)